# How to get a substring before the nth point in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get a substring that is before the nth point.
For example I have:

```
let str = "my.string.is.like.that"
```

Now suppose I want `substr= "my.string.is.like"` that is all before the 4th point. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***`split`*** and ***`join`***,

Second parameter in split is used to limit the number of element to be included in final output

```js
let str = "my.string.is.like.that"

let limited = str.split('.',4).join('.')

console.log(limited)
```